# gitlab-ci reference environmental variables in ssh command

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have the following command in my gitlab-ci.yml file: `- rsync -v -e ssh /builds/Sustersic/untitled-combat-game/build username@1.1.1.1:/var/www/html`

I tried re-writing this command with environemntal varibales:
`- rsync -v -e ssh /builds/Sustersic/untitled-combat-game/build "$HOST_USERNAME"@"$HOST_IP":/var/www/html`

But the environment variables are not getting read correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am looking at my gitlab ci and then at yours and I am equally confused. Would the "${var_name}" notation work by any chance?

Comment: Did you try the command without using double quotes around the variables ???(`$HOST_USERNAME@$HOST_IP`)

Comment: In the Gitlab CI settings, make sure that the variable is not protected or masked.If that does not work, is the runner running on linux or windows?

Comment: @Ghanima you are correct, the variable was protected and I tried running the pipeline on a non-protected branch. Will close the question.